# Reset Windows, and now Minecraft will not open

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

A few weeks ago, I reset my computer. I re-installed Minecraft, but it does not work.

**Clarification:** When I say reset, I mean I completely removed everything and reinstalled Windows by going to settings > change pc settings > update and recovery > recovery > and then I chose the "remove everything and reinstall Windows" option.

[image: This is the containing folder.]

I double click on **MinecraftLauncher.exe**, and it shows the loading circle for a few moments, but nothing else happens.

I have tried

- deleting and re-installing several times,
- downloading **Minecraft.exe**,
- downloading **Microsoft.msi**, and
- just about every other fix I could find for Windows.

**All downloads have come from the official Minecraft website**.

**Specifications, as requested:**
I am currently using Windows 8.1 with an i3 dual core processor @ 3.5 Ghz, 8 GB RAM. Not sure what else I should include

**UPDATE**
I've tried installing Java, and it did not fix the issue. 
I also checked for updates and installed all available updates, it also did not work.

**UPDATE #2**
I attempted to look at the process in a process manager, and after clicking on Minecraft, something popped up for a split second. I captured it:

[image]

Soon after ^ that popped up, it disappeared. Hopefully knowing this will help resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! :D

I've formatted your question to make it easier to read. Hopefully it attracts more traffic and upvotes, and helps you get a response.

Given that this is a technical question, could you please tell us your system specifications, including Windows version?

Comment: Do you have Java installed? To my understanding you *may* not need it, depending on which version you have downloaded.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/210907/minecraft-doesnt-need-java-installed-anymore-its-time-to-remove-it/

Seems Minecraft is standalone, now.

Comment: @Timelord yes it is *now*, but that is after (I believe) 1.8.6

Comment: It's possible your pc isn't updated completely. After your reset (when you say "reset", I *assume* you mean format?) you may need to re-update your pc. You can check this  (on windows) by going to the control panel > system and security > check for updates

Comment: When I say reset, I mean I completely removed everything and reinstalled Windows by going to settings > change pc settings > update and recovery > recovery > and then I chose the "remove everything and reinstall Windows" option. Sorry, I should have been more clear about that. But I will try what you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just a guess. Did you need to reconfigure your User after the re-installation?

Microsoft isn't that tidy if they say "re-install". In some cases, user profiles will be migrated to "help" the user after the re-installation. In this case, it might be that your Roaming Profile is still present but uses older files.

You may want to search for it in `C:\Users\<yourUsername>\AppData\Roaming` (assuming your Windows and your profiles are installed on `C:`). There will be a folder called `minecraft`. Don't delete it, just rename it to `minecraft_bak`. Retry to open your Minecraft. Maybe you'll need to reinstall Minecraft and try it again. The folder will be recreated. But if this doesn't help, you have your original Minecraft folder still as a backup.

It might be, that Minecraft has some version issues to to your Roaming Profile and your fresh Minecraft installation.

Comment: I did as you said and unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything. I found the .minecraft folder, renamed it, tried to reopen MC and it just created a new folder and still didn't work. "It might be, that Minecraft has some version issues to to your Roaming Profile and your fresh Minecraft installation." **If that is the case, what can I do?** thanks

Comment: Well the action I described above is the thing you can do. In this case I think there is some other error which may affect it.

Comment: How can I check for other errors? I'm honestly flummoxed about this whole deal, Minecraft has never failed to work for me and I'm not sure what I can do.

Comment: Well there are still some possibilities, but I'm not sure if those will be really for you. If the application crashes after some time, you might check if there is some entry in your event viewer. Maybe some kind of error message. If this won't help, you can also check what the process do and check if there are some file handles which may help you. This can be achieved with a procmon for example.

Comment: So I tried the event viewer and nothing showed up when I clicked Minecraft. Then, I opened up a process manager, clicked on Minecraft, and for a split second something popped up and I managed to screenshot it [here](http://gyazo.com/ed95d231f5b070dadd55c6208d07fa4f). It only appeared for a second before it disappeared. It appears as though MC is attempting to launch but stopping a second after it initially opens?

Comment: Conhost seems to be called by java to run something on the console. Maybe there is a permission problem after your newinstallation? Maybe there is no right to execute some application. But hard to say.

Comment: Just to be sure. You can setup a `VM` and try to run it in a really clean windows installation in your `VM`. Maybe your restore installation is corrupted.

Comment: I can't do a VM because I don't have an installation disk for Windows 8.1 or any other Windows that I could potentially use. Is there another way I could test for a restore installation corruption? And is there any other info you could use to determine what the issue is?

Comment: Well a cd won't be a problem. If your have a legit windows, you can get the download image for free from MS or create a Windows installation disc based on your windows you've installed (which is in this case not the best idea, if it may be corrupted). Well another Idea is to reinstall it under a complete new directory and try again. But if there is some kind of corruption in your windows, this won't help much I think.

Comment: I've actually discovered something about Java and my computer. Java doesn't seem to be working. For instance, I can't access the Java control panel and if I try starting Java, it flashes cmd for a few seconds then it disappears. I think this must be it considering everything I've tried. Now I'm trying to get Java to actually work but it still refuses to work. Ugh

Comment: Well in case of java you can remove it completely and reinstall it after that. Normally this should help. But I'm not sure. Minecraft is shipped with it's own JRE as far as I know.

Answer (score -2):

Try disabling your antivirus program then redownload and install, some antivirus program may be blocking a file from downloading.

Comment: The issue isn't with the download; if it was, the download would error, not trying to run the application.

Comment: I was wondering if the reset I did is somehow causing this. Before I reset my computer (I reset it to fix some problems with the computer [this is a reset as in a Windows 8.1 reset, which you do from the settings thing]), Minecraft worked fine and opened everytime I clicked on it. After the reset, I could not get it to open. I don't see how the reset could have caused this issue..but, it does seem kind of odd that MC stopped working after I did the reset.